# tuning query for updating a sum for each of a lot of users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which holds users predictions to world cup games and each prediction has a score according to real result of match. so my table (worldcup_prediction) has user_id and predic_score. I want to update users total score which is in worldcup_user table and is calculated by sum of each predictions score.
so my query for this is:

```
UPDATE worldcup_user
SET score = COALESCE((
            SELECT sum(predic_score)
            FROM worldcup_prediction
            WHERE user_id = worldcup_user.user_id
            ), 0)
```

but this query take to much time (usersCount*0.01 seconds) which with 50000 users, it's a lot.
is there a way to optimize this query?
I'm using PostgreSQL for database.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the calculation in advance and joining in the results:

```
UPDATE worldcup_user
    SET score = COALESCE(ups.pscore, 0)
    FROM worldcup_user LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT user_id, sum(predic_score) as pscore
          FROM worldcup_prediction
          GROUP BY user_id
         ) ups
         ON ups.user_id = worldcup_user.user_id;
```

It is also possible that a simple compound index would fix performance for the first query.  You would try this index:

```
create index idx_worldcup_prediction_2 on workcup_prediction(user_id, predic_score);
```

Comment: You beat me just by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, now you are running the `SELECT` statement for each user in the table.

I think it would decrease the time of execution if you would run the `SELECT SUM()` query once and then update each user with his corresponding value (by using a `JOIN` between the `SELECT SUM` query and the worldcup_user table)

Something like:

```
UPDATE wu
SET wu.score = wp.score
FROM
worldcup_user wu INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(predic_score), 0) AS 'Score', user_id
     FROM worldcup_prediction
     GROUP BY user_id) wp 
    ON wu.user_id = wp.user_id
```